# Questions Sort by Date

Tags: feature-request

I review my questions and answers regularly, but I'd like to see the list in a more efficient manner. Can DB unanswered questions be sorted by date descending?

Comment: Can you explain what page you're talking about? Many lists have options to sort by newest, relevance, votes, activity, etc.

Comment: I'm in the Database administrators meta site in the unanswered questions area. I don't see a way to sort by newest, relevance, votes or activity. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

If you go to the [Unanswered Tab > Newest](https://dba.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=newest) the questions order by the most recent unanswered questions first.  If you want the oldest unanswered, then scroll to the bottom and go to the last page.

The Newest Unanswered:

> [image]

Then scroll all the way to the bottom of the page and pick the last page:

> [image]

Comment: THanks.Dunce hat on.